# How do native speakers read "did an"?

Tags: pronunciation

How do native speakers read "did an"?

> He **did an** embarrassed little dance.
>
> The student **did an** excellent job leading his group for the school
>   project.

[sound example](https://forvo.com/phrase/the_student_did_an_excellent_job_leading_his_group_for_the_school_project./)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have repeatedly listened to the [sound example](https://forvo.com/phrase/the_student_did_an_excellent_job_leading_his_group_for_the_school_project./).

It sounds like "didn't" without the '’t'.

So its pronouncing symbol should be **['dɪdn]**.

Comment: Did you mean to post this as an answer or edit to your question? You can edit your question by clicking the [`edit`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/171579/edit) button under your question.

Comment: @userr2684291, since one can answer his or her own question ... I just think this is the answer :)

Comment: There should actually be very slightly more **a** in it than in 'didn't' without the 't'. It's subtle, but it's there. It's kind of half-way between didn & didan. the 2nd 'd' stays very soft, like didn't, but there's just a hint more 'a' behind it.